# integrating facebook login error No such module 'FacebookCore' swift4

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

i am following this link  to integrate facebook login 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started
All these pods are installed successfully

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

but when ever i am going to import  import FacebookCore in app-delegate i am facing this error
No such module 'FacebookCore'

okay now import FacebookCore work but when i ever i try to add button using this code it says
Use of unresolved identifier 'LoginButton'

```
   let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
        loginButton.center = view.center

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Comment: import FBSDKCoreKit & import FBSDKLoginKit

Comment: import work but when i try to add button it says Use of unresolved identifier 'LoginButton'

Comment: Are you trying to add LoginButton in appDelegate? and upload code for adding LoginButton.

Comment: check it bro i am adding this code into viewcontroller according to facebook documentation

Comment: FYI You need to import FacebookCore & FacebookLogin in ViewController.swift for LoginButton

Comment: it works but why facebook documentation is not proper

Comment: Its already mentioned bro. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Comment: did you open `.xcworkspace` or `.xcodeproj`? You should work in the workspace after installing the pods. Try to close Xcode and open `.xcworkspace` file.

Comment: its working now Thank JD

Comment: yes bro renatus i was did